# UserID sub-claim generated, but disappears from Identity Server 4 tokens, causing UserManager.GetUser to fail

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am building a React SPA with Identity Server 4 and dotnetcore 3.1. The Identity Server client is defined in `appsettings.json` using the `IdentityServerSPA` profile. Using `oidc-client` on the frontend, I can login successfully. Inspecting the `oidc` object, I can confirm that:

- token_type: `Bearer`
- scope: `openid profile OpenWorkShopAPI`
- profile.sub: (my user ID)
- profile.name: (my username)

If I subsequently try to call the API (either with `Authorization: Bearer` as the `id_token` or the `access_token`), there is no `sub` claim present. Therefore, `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` fails.

Enumerating and printing the claims, I see:

```
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "nbf" "1601597732"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "exp" "1601598032"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "iss" "http://dev.openwork.shop:5000"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "aud" "OpenWorkShopAPI"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "iat" "1601597732"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "at_hash" "MoAqNfND0ct1mUFKpUtgcg"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "s_hash" "D81HZF_ii2r0i5-4_ZxnLA"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "sid" "cdMH0nFKdikldL1Gy3S3Eg"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" "fdf0023d-7ae9-4aaf-87fe-0f320b869171"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "auth_time" "1601582136"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider" "local"
Claim: "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity" "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences" "pwd"
```

Based upon this, I  can work around this by accessing the name claim to find the ID directly:

```
string CurrentUserId => User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
```

But that seems neither correct nor ideal.

I have noticed that all of my MySQL tables (except `AspNetUsers`) remain empty. There are no values in `AspNetUserClaims`, for example. Yet, as I showed above, the `oidc-client` is able to successfully see the `sub` claim for the user ID.

Since I am using the `DefaultIdentity` and `AddApiAuthorization`, I do not expect to need to add any special logic to implement such sub-claims, and am not sure why it is missing on the API calls.

Configuration:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserProfile>(options => {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 64;
      }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<OWSData>();

      WebHostOptions webHost = configuration.GetSection("WebHost").Get<WebHostOptions>();
      string root = webHost.Url;

      services.AddIdentityServer((options) => {
        options.PublicOrigin = root;
        options.IssuerUri = root;
        options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = $"{root}/account/login";
        options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = $"{root}/account/logout";
        options.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = $"{root}/account/error";
        options.UserInteraction.ConsentUrl = $"{root}/account/terms-of-service";
        options.UserInteraction.DeviceVerificationUrl = $"{root}/account/device-verification";
      }).AddApiAuthorization<UserProfile, OWSData>(options => {
        // Serilog.Log.Information("Clients: {@clients}", options.Clients);
      });
      services.AddScoped<ICurrentUser, CurrentUser>();
      services.AddTransient<IReturnUrlParser, AuthReturnUrl>();

      // Auth (JWT)
      services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                 // options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               })
              .AddCookie((options) => {
                 webHost.ConfigureCookie(CookieName, options.Cookie);
                 options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                 options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/denied";
                 options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
                 options.SlidingExpiration = true;
               })
              .AddIdentityServerJwt()
              .AddGoogle(options => {
                 ConfigureOAuth(options, "Google", configuration, webHost);
               })
              .AddGitHub(options => {
                 ConfigureOAuth(options, "GitHub", configuration, webHost);
                 options.Scope.Add("user:email");
                 options.EnterpriseDomain = configuration["GitHub:EnterpriseDomain"];
               });

      services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        // options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
      });

      // Auth (Password)
      services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
        //Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        //Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        //User settings
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
          "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
      });

      // Cookies
      services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        webHost.ConfigureCookie(CookieName, options.Cookie);
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` on `JwtBearerAuthentication` middleware, is mapping some claims by default. Along these mappings, `sub` claim is mapped to the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`. Mappings are listed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs#L50).

You can change the code on API to  set the name identifier claim as `NameClaimType`. `NameClaimType` is used to set `Identity.Name`.

Here is the code change required on API:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
                options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.Audience = "api1";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"//To set Identity.Name 
                    };         
                });
```

Here is a sample working code: https://github.com/nahidf/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/ids4-4/src/CoreApi/Startup.cs#L36

Edit: If you are using `IdentityServerSPA` template to create the project, its just a template which has some extension methods and internally using same methods we use in manual setup

For-example per [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-profiles) `IdentityServerJwt` is to do this:

> Represents an API that is hosted alongside with IdentityServer.
> The app is configured to have a single scope that defaults to the app name.

To achieve above purpose [IdentityServerJwt](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Authentication/AuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L33) is calling `AddJwtBearer` internally.

And also it uses [IdentityServerJwtDescriptor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Configuration/IdentityServerJwtApiDescriptor.cs) to to add the api resource.

So if we go with manual setup or just using IDS4 templates, we can see calls in our code.

In this case cause you have access to [AddJwtBearer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Authentication/AuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L47) as its called inside the extension method, you can change the `JwtBearerOptions` afterwards like this:

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>("Bearer",
                options =>
                {
                    new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"//To set Identity.Name 
                    };
                });
```

You have another option too which will remove all the mappings I mentioned above, its to add this code on StartUp at the first line.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

Comment: I'm confused about the difference between `AddIdentityServerJwt` and `AddJwtBearer`. Based upon looking at the code for the former, your code seems to omit things like adding the `IdentityServerJwtDescriptor`. Was this intentional? Will it break something else in my app? And how is it that the `React-Auth` template works just fine without this code? I copied the user manager code directly from the identity UI scaffolding. I mean, shouldn't the identity server work out of the box? The user manager comes with it, why do I have to add special code just to make its default user login work?

Comment: I tried to explain these on edit on response. about why react template works I suggest you to check `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap` to see whats going on. This issue has nothing to do with IdentityServer its all happening on `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`

Comment: Thanks for being so thorough!